# how to recheck file in Arduino SD card

Tags: pointers, arduino, sd-card

I am trying to create a list of files on my SD card this is easy enough to do once but the moment I run the program more than once the list become either shortened or the program say there is no files at all.

To make this as easy as possible I am using the SD example that comes with the arduino SD library and just putting the setup part ( that would normally run once ) in the loop part.
Heres what I have with that.

```
#include <SD.h>

File root;

void setup()  
{
// Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
Serial.begin(9600);
 while (!Serial) {
  ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
}


Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
// On the Ethernet Shield, CS is pin 4. It's set as an output by default.
// Note that even if it's not used as the CS pin, the hardware SS pin 
// (10 on most Arduino boards, 53 on the Mega) must be left as an output 
// or the SD library functions will not work. 
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

if (!SD.begin(10)) {
  Serial.println("initialization failed!");
  return;
}
Serial.println("initialization done.");


}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("hit any key then enter to run the list");
    while(!Serial.available())
    {;}
  Serial.read();
  root = SD.open("/");

  printDirectory(root, 0);

Serial.println("done!");

// nothing happens after setup finishes.
  }

 void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
    while(true) {

   File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
   if (! entry) {
     // no more files
     //Serial.println("**nomorefiles**");
     break;
     }
   for (uint8_t i=0; i<numTabs; i++) {
     Serial.print('\t');
      }
   Serial.print(entry.name());
   if (entry.isDirectory()) {
     Serial.println("/");
     printDirectory(entry, numTabs+1);
   } else {
     // files have sizes, directories do not
     Serial.print("\t\t");
     Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
   }
 }
}
```

But then I get this weird output after running it

Initializing SD card...initialization done.

hit any key then enter to run the list

HFBVYRG.TXT     7

THBVFG.TXT      7

WAZXDSQ.TXT     7

QAZXSW.TXT      21

WSXZAQ.TXT      7

1478523.TXT     7

QWSDFRE.TXT     7

ZXCVBNM.TXT     7

MKOLIJY.TXT     7

done!

hit any key then enter to run the list

HFBVYRG.TXT     7

THBVFG.TXT      7

WAZXDSQ.TXT     7

QAZXSW.TXT      21

WSXZAQ.TXT      7

1478523.TXT     7

QWSDFRE.TXT     7

ZXCVBNM.TXT     7

MKOLIJY.TXT     7

done!

hit any key then enter to run the list

HFBVYRG.TXT     7

THBVFG.TXT      7

WAZXDSQ.TXT     7

QAZXSW.TXT      21

done!

hit any key then enter to run the list

done!

hit any key then enter to run the list

done!

hit any key then enter to run the list

done!

hit any key then enter to run the list

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

as you can see it gets shorter and shorter then just stops altogether.

Does anyone have any ideas why ?

I have tried playing around with pointers and closing and reopening the file but I have come up with nothing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No good can come from mismatched open()'s and close()'s.  You open the root directory every pass through the loop:

```
root = SD.open("/");
```

but never

```
root.close();
```

First, fix this error and also check that when you open the root that you succeed before trying to print a listing:

```
root = SD.open("/");
if(root) {
  printDirectory(root, 0);
  Serial.println("done!");
  root.close();
}
else {
  Serial.println("failed to open directory");
}
```

Second, close the files that are opened in the directory walk

```
void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {

  while(true) {
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    ...
    entry.close();
  }
  return;
}
```

Lastly, consider not blocking in the loop().  Other things can happen outside your loop() and they will be blocked indefinitely depending on how long you wait to hit a key.  A more typical code pattern is to spin wildly through the loop() as opposed to blocking waiting for user input.  For example:

```
boolean bNeedPrompt = true;

void loop() {
  // Show the prompt once, then mark as displayed so that text does not
  // continuously scroll on the screen
  if(bNeedPrompt) {
    Serial.println("hit any key then enter to run the list");
    bNeedPrompt = false;
  }

  if(Serial.available()) {
    Serial.read();
    // do action
    // set flag so that prompt will display again
    bNeedPrompt = true;
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: I can not tell you how happy I am hahahahah !!! Thank you so much this has been bugging me for days. I will take a good look at your code but the first time I did it on the basic code it worked perfectly :) Just one last thing but it is just for general knowledge do you know why it gave the list twice then only went messed up ? if you don't know I really dont mind THANKS AGAIN

Comment: OMG! this is also a fix to my problem. thanx!

Answer (score 1):

jdr5ca's answer addresses a lot of the problems with your setup - by not closing files you are going to be leaking resources which won't end well.  It is particularly important on such a low memory setup as the Arduino, which has only 2k RAM for the original chips, so worth bearing in mind throughout your code.

Short answer for your remaining question: it won't be entirely predictable, but low memory is likely the cause of your problem.  Read on for more details.

I've had some similar experiences with the SD library recently, though not with such an obvious cause.  I found that if the free memory on my system got below about 500 bytes (a quarter of the total RAM) then the SD library starts to behave very oddly when trying to list directories.

I saw similar things to you, for example:

1. list entries under root directory and find two sub-directories
2. list entries in one of those sub-directories, worked fine
3. list entries under root directory and now I find only one sub-directory!  The one I had listed the contents of has vanished!
4. I could still list the contents of the sub-directory fine, ie. it is still there!
5. resetting the Arduino and starting again gave the same results, again showing that the files were still present on SD card

I think all of this comes down to SD library being both quite memory hungry (`#include SD.h` uses up 500 bytes off the bat!), and not handling low memory errors particularly obviously.

So if things are acting strangely then:

1. check your memory usage (see eg. `freeRam()` from http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory)
2. reduce your memory usage where ever possible.  In rough order:

   - remove libraries you don't need
   - get rid of any hard coded strings that you don't need (eg. in calls to `Serial.print()`)
   - for hard coded strings you do need make them as short as possible, and store them in flash (eg. `Serial.print(F("String in flash"));`) rather than RAM
   - you can't stick format strings (eg. for `snprintf`) in flash currently, so avoid using those and just build up the output manually (it is more long handed but saves memory)
   - make sure you are using appropriate variable types everywhere (ie. the smallest sized type that will suit your purposes) - especially important if you have any arrays, for obvious reasons!